# I cant display data from laravel api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to get data from my laravel app, and display it in Vue CLI.
I see the Response, but I can not display it in the VUE application.

[image]
When i do get to example API it's works, but not from my laravel server.

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <h1>{{ results }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
      return{
         results: null
      }
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
            .then(response => {
                this.results = response.data.results
            })
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You results appear to be an object, inside an array.  What happens if you change `{{ results }}` to `{{ results[0].name }}`?

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: Do you have the `Vue.js devtools` extension installed in your browser?  Can you make sure `results` is being populated by your response?  Can you post the controller method?

Comment: I think the second problem is that you have `this.results = response.data.results` when according to your Network tab, there is no `results` property.  It should just be `this.results = response.data`.

Comment: Okey, so now i have `axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/').then(response => {this.results = response.data})` and about Vue extension my result is null

Comment: Did you recompile your Vues after making these changes?  e.g., `npm run watch` or `npm run dev`  What about `console.log(response)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

To connect laravel API with front-end i need to do add barryvdh/laravel-cors by composer.

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

Next add middleware in  `app/Http/Kernel.php` to enable using API outside laravel APP. In my problem to Vue Cli.

Answer (score 1):

Your results are being received as an array of objects, a JSON encoded Laravel collection.  You need to single out the object you want to display, and then a property of that object.

```html
<div id="app">
    <h1>{{ results[0].name }}</h1>
</div>
```

However, you should really only be returning one object if this is the case from your controller method, not an array of objects. (e.g., `->first()` instead of `->get()`)

```html
<div id="app">
    <h1>{{ result.name }}</h1>
</div>
```

Collections are generally for displaying multiple results in lists, table, options, etc.:

```html
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <!-- v-for will loop through results -->
        <li v-for="(result, index) in results">{{ result.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Also, your results declaration needs to be adjusted according to the Network response.

```
this.results = response.data.results;
```

Should be:

```
this.results = response.data;
```

Or alternatively, your controller response needs to be:

```php
return response()->json(['results' => $results]);
```

Comment: I do like you say, and this is the result.  https://imgur.com/a/jiGqJkZ

Comment: Since you changed to `['results' => $results]`, did you also change back to `this.results = response.data.results`?  It was one or the other.  The image was helpful, but I can't see your `.then` statement.

Comment: Yes, but now i don't see response in chrome. Look on my next image. https://imgur.com/fEb1ARP

Comment: That doesn't make sense unless something else happened to the request.  You should receive some response, one way or another.  Especially if PostMan is giving you one.  I really want to help you, but I'm not sure what else to provide at this point.  It's difficult to see everything at once since you have limited screen space.  We could try moving this to a chat, if I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: I see you also appear to have multiple javascript errors.  What's going on in the console?  Any of these could potentially be halting the operation of your application.

Comment: Ok, i create new laravel app and just return in route simple string, and try to get it form Vue( i create vue app) and nothing. Look ad this. https://imgur.com/a/g0htWVL

Comment: Response is an object, and the text "Laravel" is an item in an array.  You need `response.data` to get the full data, and `response.data[0]` to get the value Laravel.  So, `this.info = response.data[0]`.  I do not believe Vue will display an object or array as text.  What about `console.log(response)`?

Comment: console.log(response) is null

Comment: Can you show both routes?  You should have one for the view and another for the request.  Can you show the blade file also?

Comment: Check out this Gist I made and see if you are missing something.  https://gist.github.com/matticustard/248371ef6c2380ddb08d61a86741f183

Comment: But I have two others spearate repository, one i install laravel, and delete resource files this is server, and one repository for front-end Vue Cli. I have zero Vue files in laravel app i wanted to laravel app only for API, and separate Vue for front. No blade flies.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was trying to figure out what was going on with your routes and it wasn't making sense.  I think this should eventually prompt us to open a chat if we keep talking.

Comment: But the same principles still apply.  What happens if you alter your Vue file to look like mine, and use the data I provided in my `/data` route, just changing the request url accordingly?